# Creating WiX Setup for a desktop application with C# VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, installation

I need to create a setup file to install silently a desktop application (with MS System Center) in 1000 computers approx. I downloaded WiX and installed in my computer. In Visual Studio 2012 I created a new **Setup Project** and added the desktop app as reference.

It created me a Product.wxs file, I did some reaserch and modified it a bit from a basic tutorial I found. When I compiled the project it creates me the .msi file. If I try to install it my computer it runs creates a .exe file and exits. When I run the exe nothing happens, the form doesn't open and I get a compatibility warning. My customers have Windows 7 with the 4.5 Framework.

Also, will I have problems using system center? I saw it creates a cab file that is required for the installation.

This are the tutorials I used: [LINK](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_first_votive_project.htm) and [LINK](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_package_manifest.htm)

This is is my wxs file:

```
<code class="prettyprint">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="RMS_Setup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Familia" UpgradeCode="1234567890">
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
<MediaTemplate />

<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="RMS_Setup" Level="1">
<ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
</Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="RMS_Setup" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="ProductComponent">
            <File Source="$(var.KPG.ADSEF.RMS.DESKTOP.TargetPath)" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

The two links that you provided are for two different things. The first is for creating and MSI and the second is for creating a bootstrapper (a program to install multiple MSIs strung together).

On to your question. As long as the MSI is exiting without an error and the file is there to use, then the MSI is doing exactly what you are telling it to. If the EXE is not working, then that means that the executable has an issue or there is something else that is needed that you are not accomplishing with the MSI.

There might be a better answer to your question, but before that can be given you have to provide the error that you are receiving and debug your executable a little bit.